Energy price prediction with time series
I am working in a project with time series data. I have to predict $$\text{return}_t=\frac{\text{price}_t - \text{price}_{t-1}}{\text{price}_{t-1}}$$
I select feature by feature engineering. The previous lag of return and lag of 1st difference of return are the features. I read some paper where they use lag of 1st difference of return to predict 1st difference of return series. Can I use the features to predict the return series, not the 1st difference of return series?
